# Редакция технического предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение и его примерная редакция. Вопрос: надо ли несогласованное определение "шириной 8 модулей зацепления" выделять запятыми с двух сторон? И вообще согласны ли вы с такой "примерной" редакцией?

С. 66 Для целей предельно возможного технического уровня решения преобразовательного механизма с жертвой унификационной широты были предусмотрены в осевом измерении 4 градации ширины зубчатых колес рядов: от плоской шириной 8 модулей зацепления до широкой  32 модуля, а в другом, радиальном 4 серии крупности зубьев: 48 у корон тяжелой серии, 96 –  основной, 136 – легкой и, наконец, 196 – мелкой серии при равенстве их диаметров и присоединительных размеров.

Для целей предельно возможного технического уровня решения преобразовательного механизма с жертвой унификационной широты были предусмотрены в осевом измерении 4 градации ширины зубчатых колес рядов: от плоской, шириной 8 модулей зацепления до широкой – 32 модуля. А в другом, радиальном – 4 серии крупности зубьев: 48 у корон тяжелой серии, 96 –  основной, 136 – легкой и, наконец, 196 – мелкой серии при равенстве их диаметров и присоединительных размеров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаемый вариант:

Для целей предельно возможного технического уровня решения преобразовательного механизма с жертвой унификационной широты были предусмотрены в осевом измерении 4 градации ширины зубчатых колес рядов: от плоской, шириной 8 модулей зацепления, до широкой – 32 модуля.

Несогласованное определение "шириной 8 модулей зацепления" обособляем, так как это не отличительный, а уточняющий признак (градация уже имеет названия: от плоской до широкой).

Тире обозначает неполную конструкцию ("до широкой, шириной 32 модуля").

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: "...с жертвой унификационной широты..." - это же издевательство над русским языком и техническими понятиями

Answer (score 0):

Запятыми можно выделить только в том случае, если " плоской" не является определением к "шириной 8 модулей зацепления". В противном случае запятая не нужна.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. И "плоской", и "шириной 8 модулей зацепления"  - определения к "градации ширины".

Comment: А-а, все ясно. Здесь слово "плоской" является существительным в родительном падеже. А  "шириной 8 модулей зацепления - несогласованное определение, являющиеся уточнением  к "плоской''. Запятая нужна.Ср. аналогичное предложение: " Только узкое, САЖЕНЕЙ В ТРИСТА, полоса плодородной земли составляет владение казаков. ( Л. Т.).
Об уточняющих определениях : Справочник-практикум. Д.Э. Розенталь. Стр.195.

Comment: Только, наверное, узкаЯ.

Comment: Да, простите, опечатка.

Answer (score 0):

Никогда не встречал технических текстов, которые были бы НАСТОЛЬКО непонятны. Непонятны именно из-за построения предложений. Выделять запятыми-то надо, только это не спасёт.

Comment: Полностью согласен. Текст чересчур запутан!

Comment: И я согласна. :) А что если эти предложения разделить точкой с запятой?

Comment: Писал технарь, совершенно не разумеющий в гуманитарном плане